# Diode Temperature effect

Tags: diodes, temperature

How will temperature affect the output of a semiconductor diode?

Comment: Reverse leakage current will also increase - many of the answers to [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/why-exactly-do-chips-start-malfunctioning-once-they-overheat/13903#13903) will also apply to what you have asked here

Comment: Many books could be written and armies of PhD students employed to investigate this problem as stated, and there would still be more to learn.  What do you want to know about the effects of temperature on a diode?  This question is overly broad, and could be closed.

Comment: Also, I've removed your "Hi" and "Thanks" lines per the site guidelines.  They are considered good manners in some contexts, but the Stack Exchange network is not one of these places: Here, they're noise and distract from the asking and answering of questions. Please don't do this in the future! <irony>Thanks!</irony>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **forward voltage** of a Si diode will drop by about 2.1 mV/°C (negative temperature coefficient, NTC). For a Ge diode this NTC is a bit higher at 2.5 mV/°C.
The effect is almost **perfectly linear**, so if you want you can make the diode a **temperature sensor** by supplying it with a constant current.

**Reverse current** increases exponentially with rising temperature. For a [1N4148](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf) it increases tenfold for every 20°C temperature rise.

Comment: first of all , thanks for your answer.Lastly,I want to a question.What websites&books can you  recommended related semiconductor devices?

Comment: @Cell-o - The question about electronics books has been asked a few times in the past, read e.g. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/books-for-basic-electronics

Comment: @stevenvh, this is specifically for Si diodes, or does this apply to all diodes.

Comment: @Kortuk - this is for Si, I'll add this to the answer. Ge diodes have a higher tempco. Don't know the exact value though.

Comment: @Stevenvh, I was 99% sure of that, but thought I should ask, figured a short and sweet answer needed that added.

Comment: @Stevenvh - what is the reverse recovery time in diode?

Comment: @Cell-o - That question is (mostly) unrelated to the effect of temperature on a diode.  Please post it as a new question, if it's not a duplicate of [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/what-is-a-fast-2a-type-diode).